# A leitura de arquivos no Python é atualizada em tempo real?

Tags: python, arquivo, multithreading

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde vou criar um multithreading que irá ler um arquivo `.json` e baseado em uma chave deste arquivo (`status: 'pending'` ou `status: 'completed'`) eu vou executar uma ação ou não.

A idéia é que essa ação não seja executada duas vezes no mesmo item, para isso quando eu finalizar a ação em um item o status será mudado de `pending` para `completed`. A minha dúvida é, como o arquivo vai ser lido por várias instancias do Python ao mesmo tempo, eu posso confiar que a chave será atualizada em tempo real, ou preciso reabrir o arquivo toda vez que for verificar se é necessário mexer naquele item novamente?

Comment: Pelo que está descrevendo vai ter que garantir isso no código, a linguagem não faz nada por conta própria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta curta é: você precisa reabrir o arquivo e ler seu conteúdo de novo.
Sempre que um arquivo é lido - não só em Python, mas em qualquer linguagem nos sistemas operacionais convencionais, o sistema faz uma cópia dos dados do arquivo para as estruturas de dados em memória.

Mas sim, é possível reler os conteúdos do mesmo arquivo sem abrir e fechar o mesmo, se você chamar sempre o `flush` do lado que escreve no arquivo, e usar corretamenbte o método `seek` no momento da leitura: é algo que introduz mais complexidade, principalmente se você não tem alguma experiência com isso.

Por outro lado, se você está fazendo tudo no mesmo programa, não precisa usar arquivos para sinalizar tarefas completas entre uma thread e outra - pode usar um objeto do tipo `queue` para comunicação entre threads - ou mesmo variáveis a nível de módulo (globais) - dependendo da sua arquitetura.
Queues são mais robustas, e a prova de condições de corrida, no entanto:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html